# MySQL syntax error: check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version

Tags: php, mysql

I've been pulling my hair out over this and am hoping somebody here can help. Any help would be much appreciated.

I'm using WAMP on a 64-bit Win 7 platform locally, and the version of MySQL packaged with WAMP is 5.0.1a. I've also embedded smf into a Wordpress template. Code from the header.php file follows, as well as the specific error:

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND xxxx.xxxx_members.ID_MEMBER =' at line 7"

```php
                    <?php 
                    // Get race image
                    $members = xxxx_FORUM_MEMBERS_TABLE;
                    $forum_id = xxxx_forum_user_id();
                    $sql = "SELECT users.race, {$members}.memberName, ranks.rank
                            FROM 
                                {$members}, users 
                                    LEFT JOIN ranks 
                                    ON users.id = ranks.user_id 
                            WHERE users.forum_id = {$forum_id} 
                            AND {$members}.ID_MEMBER = {$forum_id}";
                    $users = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
                    $race = "unknown";
                    $name = "";
                    $rank = null;
                    if ($user = mysql_fetch_object($users)) {
                        $race = $user->race;
                        $name = $user->memberName;
                        $rank = $user->rank;
                        if ($rank != null) {
                            // Prefix 1th, 2nd 3rd, 4th
                            $order = $rank % 10;
                            if ($rank > 10 || $rank < 21) $rank .= 'th';
                            else if ($order == 1) $rank .= 'th';
                            else if ($order == 2) $rank .= 'nd';
                            else if ($order == 3) $rank .= 'rd';
                            else                  $rank .= 'th';
                        }
                    } 
                    ?>
```

Comment: Can you give us the value of $members?  Is it being assigned to a constant in "$members = xxxx_FORUM_MEMBERS_TABLE;"  What's the value of the constant?

Comment: Basic debugging: `echo $sql;` What do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Given your error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND xxxx.xxxx_members.ID_MEMBER =' at line 7

It appears you are selecting `db.table`. You should try the following syntax:

```
SELECT tbl1.col1
FROM db.tbl1
WHERE tbl1.col1 ...
```

And not:

```
SELECT tbl1.col1
FROM db.tbl1
WHERE db.tbl1.col1 ...
```